# Find a value within array of structures

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

this might have been asked before, but didn't quite find... or what I found was old.

I have an array of structures like so:

[image]

Isn't there a CFML function that will allow me to check if "test@email.com" already exists under any of the structures "toAddress" ? I can obviously loop my array, check and break if found, but wondering if something already exists for this ?

Thank you.
Pat

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `arrayFind()` with a callback function. Using your data structure above and assume the array is named `myArray`

```
if( 
    !arrayFind( myArray, function( item ){
        return item.toAddress == 'test@email.com'
    })
){
    // do stuff if address is not used.
}
```

Comment: Works! Thanks. One question though: this means however that it'll still loop through all the array element even if it found a match, correct ? If so, is there any way I could tell the arrayFind() to break if function returned true ?

Comment: `arrayFind()` returns the first index that matches the logic you provide in the callback. I am not sure of the internal logic, but it seems it would break after the first element found. A way to test this would be to add a `writeDump()` to dump the email in the callback to see if it outputs all of them.

Comment: For future readers: `arrayFind()` will stop looking once it finds the 1st instance. It's a fairly efficient function for doing this. https://trycf.com/gist/af2e5fe9253fab408c6c21cfa490a6ae/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your time and help :)